# Can my chromebook connect to an external monitor with crouton?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, chromebook

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 from a chromebook using crouton. Plugging in my external monitor with an hdmi cable and issuing `$ xrandr` returns

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576       50.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480       60.0     59.9  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

However, issuing

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of eDP1
```

produces no output. The monitor works fine with my other laptop (which runs Ubuntu 14.04 natively). The monitor also works when I switch back to Chrome OS. Is it possible to get my monitor to work with crouton?

Answer (score 1):

I found a somewhat-satisfactory workaround.

If I log out of crouton and move my chrome window in chromeos to the external monitor, I can log back into crouton and get ubuntu on the external monitor. The problem now is that the laptop screen itself is blank. However, issuing

```
$ xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of HDMI2
```

gives me what I want. Of course, the problem here is that logging out and back into my session is annoying so I'd still be interested in a solution that addresses the original problem.

Comment: Another downside to this solution is that I end up with the original problem every time the chromebook goes to sleep.